# Other editors that can use slime/swank?

Tags: emacs, ide, slime, swank

I have been quite happy with Emacs/slime+swank for a long time, and was just wondering if there are any other editors/IDEs that can connect to a swank instance?

Comment: Never cease to be amused at the project names I see...

Answer (score 3):

[MCLIDE](http://mclide.in-progress.com/) can connect to Swank servers. (See [the MCLIDE tour](http://mclide.in-progress.com/tour) -- the very bottom of the page -- for a notice to confirm this. I recall reading about swank-clojure & MCLIDE recently... Not sure if they work together yet, but at the very least there's someone out there who's competent and interested in bringing them together.)

Answer (score 1):

Vim can connect to a Swank server; see the [Slimv](https://github.com/kovisoft/slimv) plugin for doing it; it works very good.